# if use android:process to start a new process, will this process load the all the dex again?

Tags: android

if use `android:process` to start a new process, will this process load the all the dex again? if so, will this be really slow? Both two process will share the resource of the 'loaded dex'

Comment: No, it wont load it again. Both will share the resources, as both process belongs to same app so will share same resources .he core intention to use multiple processes is because android has limit on the max memory consuption above witch it will be cached. In ios this is not the case. So developers must keep process within the heap limit, if not break it to multiple processes..

Comment: How dose these two process share the resource? what is the IPC methoud? As I konw, the data between the two process is not sharing, if want to sharing, must have some IPC methoud.So In this case, what is it, I have read the source code, but I can not find it.

Comment: 1) You are confused, resources are strings.xml, drawables, menus, JNI, Layouts. And Data is mostly app data like temp files and database

Comment: 2) Processes can share resources but not the data

Comment: 3) If you want to access database from different process then just make its own.

Comment: 4) If you want to share data ( intent data ) while starting another process you can still pass it via intent

Comment: I am unaware about IPC

Comment: @Rushikant Pawar IPC means Inter-Process Communication. By the way, I know the process share the resource, but in this case, One process loaded the apk's dex file into this process's memory space, if another process want to use  this dex file, also it should load the dex file into its memory space too....So come back to my question, how the seonde process visit the first process's memory where the dex file exits, how the seconde process know the first process has loaded the dex file? So why not `android:process` 's component loaded the dex file agin?

Comment: I know IPC just don't know how to implement it via code, there is some language aidl which is used. DEX FILE IS NOT LOADED AGAIN AND AGAIN THAT IS FOR SURE, DOES NOT MATTER DO YOU HAVE 1 / 2/ 1000 PROCESSES.

Comment: As per your question, the answer is NO. implement it. You will come to know, that it will not be loaded again and again, there is limit to memory heap of a single process, there is no limit to dex

Comment: =-=, I know the answer is the seconde process won't load the dex repeatly, I just very confused why the second process can read the first porcess's load result...And, in your last comment, the `NO` is just no or some abbreviation of `computer science` words to implement the way of my question.

Comment: Will you please edit your question and do not keep it theoretical, just show some random implementation and its results and also let us know what is desired. AFAIK i have answered your question without down voting in very first comment, even if your question is not as per SO guidelines..!! I know you are confused and also know that you have no need to implement 2 or 3 or 4 processes to what your requirement is..!! So edit it, let me know what you want, and just be developer while writing question, don't be bothered how and what and why OS is doing what and How?